# Magento\SwatchesGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Product\Options\DataProvider\SwatchDataProvider does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

[image]

`Magento\SwatchesGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Product\Options\DataProvider\SwatchDataProvider` does not exist the error while i using php bin/magento s:d:c

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check with following commands from magento root dir

```
php bin/magento module:status Magento_SwatchesGraphQl
```